# Nontrivial solutions to $-y'' = \ell y$, $y(0) = 0$, $y(1) = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working through Coddington ODEs. I have come across the following problem:

Determine all complex numbers $\ell$ for which the problem

$-y'' = \ell y$, $y(0) = 0$, $y(1) = 0$

has a non-trivial solutions, and compute such a solution for each these $\ell$.

My work so far is:

I found the characteristic equation to be

$r^2 + \ell = 0$

This implies that $r_1 = i\sqrt{\ell}$ and $r_2 = -i\sqrt{\ell}$.

This gives a general solution of $y = C_1 \cos{x\sqrt{\ell}} + C_2 \sin{x\sqrt{\ell}}$.

After plugging in the initial conditions, I found that $C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = \frac{1}{\sin{\sqrt{\ell}}}$

From this, I concluded that this is valid for $\ell \ne k^2 \pi^2$ for integer $k$.

However, the answer in the book says that $\ell = n^2 \pi^2$ for natural numbers $n$ and that $y_n = \sin{n\pi x}$. I can't seem to see why this is true.

Comment: It looks like you used $y(1)=1$ instead of $y(1)=0$ in finding $C_2$.

Comment: Ah yes I have. Embarrassing mistake, but it does make sense. Thanks for pointing it out!